# Specific knapsack-like

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I am looking for some ideas how to deal with this specific knapsack problem (I believe it is knapsack-like problem although I might be mistaken).

As input we get set of numbers, and each can be positive or negative - we don't know that.
We have to **find minimum possible *absolute* value of sum of some these numbers**.
We don't have to use all numbers. We have to do additions (or subtractions) in same order in which numbers are given and we have to start with first number (and add or subtract following ones).

Example would be:

```
4 11 5 5 => 0
because 4+11-5-5 = 0

10 3 9 4 100 => 2
because 10-3-9 = -2
```

In second example we skipped two last numbers - because adding next numbers wouldn't give us smaller absolute number.

Amount of numbers can be up to 5,000
, and the sum of them won't over exceed 10,000

They are integers

Comment: Is the range of the numbers given? Are they integers?

Comment: Janne yes. Sum of these numbers won't over exceed 10,000 and yes they are integers (but only positive of course). I am sorry I didn't mention that in post.

Comment: I suggest to study [the dynamic programming solution to the subset sum problem](http://www.skorks.com/2011/02/algorithms-a-dropbox-challenge-and-dynamic-programming/). This problem is slightly different but idea behind the solution applies.

Comment: Do we always want to use a prefix of our sequence, or we can skip some numbers and use a subsequence? In the former case, this is indeed a variation of the knapsack problem: pretend that for a prefix of length `k`, you start with taking all the values as negative (so that the base sum is `-a1 + -a2 + ... + -ak`), and then possibly switch some negative signs to positive (switching from `-ai` to `+ai` adds an object of weight `2*ai` to the knapsack). In the latter case, we get the third option to skip an object, thus adding `1*ai` to the knapsack.

Comment: Both examples are incorrect: 4+11-5-5=5, while 4-11+5=-2 is best, and in the second one the best is 10+3-9-4=0

Comment: @JanneKarila you are completely right, my mistake... thanks for watchfulness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to explore all combinations of addition and subtraction of 5000 numbers, you would have to go through 2<sup>5000</sup>−1 ≈ 1.4⋅10<sup>1505</sup> alternatives. That's obviously not reasonable. However, since the sum of the numbers is at most 10000, we know that all partial sums (including subtraction) must lie between -10000 and 10000, so there can be less than 20000 different sums. If you only consider different sums when you work through the 5000 positions you have less than 100 million sums to consider, which is not that much work for a computer.

---

Example: suppose the first three numbers are 5,1,1. The possible sums that include exactly three numbers are

```
5+1+1=7
5+1-1=5
5-1+1=5
5-1-1=3
```

Before adding the fourth number it is important to recognize that you have only three unique results from the four computations.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Could you elaborate? How do I consider only different sums?

Comment: This is nice idea, but it is still too slow. A little change in rules - now I am interested only in the lowest value of sum of all numbers, but it doesn't make significant difference.
http://ideone.com/0KnSBa
This is my implementation, I hope my algo is clear to understand. Output is 100% right (it is official test). I multiplied the same test to get measurable execution time. 
Algorithm is important part there, you can ignore i/o stuff.

Comment: My code style isn't too great so maybe I will describe my implementation:

1. I start with first number as the only possible current sum 

2. I go for next number, I consider two possibilities (addition or subtraction) and then add results to _set_

3. And then I use this set of possible sums to add/sub another number to it. Since its _set_ I will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Okay I managed to do it. I used the fact that sums can only be between -10000 and 10000 so I replaced _set_ with index based (I created big 20k elements table)  remembering previous sums which is as fast as it can be.
Still I got 0.10 execution time, best solutions have 0.00